# Fetching data from storage doesn't refresh page content

Tags: angular, promise, observable, ionic2

In my Ionic 2 app I'm getting data from the SqlStorage and from a HTTP.get request. When I get the data from the HTTP request my page refreshes as expected using the new data, but when I get the data from the SqlStorage it doesn't refresh and the new data is only shown when I 'pull to refresh'.

PS: I'm using TypeScript.

This is the SqlStorage get:

```
 oldFeeds() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    this.storage.get('feeds').then(data => {
      resolve(JSON.parse(data));
    });
  });
}
```

And this is the HTTP get:

```
feeds() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    this.http.get('http://foo.bar').map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data => {
      resolve(data);
    },
    e => reject(e));
  });
}
```

These methods are inside a service and the calls to them are exactly the same:

```
this.feedsService.oldFeeds().then(data => {
  this.feeds = data;
  this.entries = this.feeds[this.activeIndex].entries;
});

this.feedsService.feeds().then(data => {
  this.feeds = data;
  this.entries = this.feeds[this.activeIndex].entries;
});
```

Any ideas on why this is happening and what could I do to solve it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**update**

To nudge Angulars change detection "manually" you can use 
[ApplicationRef](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/ApplicationRef-class.html#!#tick)

```
import {ApplicationRef} from 'angular2/core';

constructor(private appRef:ApplicationRef) {}

oldFeeds() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    this.storage.get('feeds').then(data => {
      resolve(JSON.parse(data));
      this.appRef.tick();
    });
  });
}
```

**original**

didn't work - see comments

```
constructor(private zone:NgZone) {}

oldFeeds() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    this.storage.get('feeds').then(data => {
      this.zone.run(() => {
        resolve(JSON.parse(data));
      });
    });
  });
}
```

Looks like SqlStorage API isn't patched by Angulars zone and the call needs to be brought back into Angulars zone "manually" for change detection to run.

See also [Triggering Angular2 change detection manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34827334/triggering-angular2-change-detection-manually)

Comment: Thank you! Although the NgZone didn't work, the ApplicationRef worked!

Comment: Might be related to the use of `Promise`. I haven't used it in that context.

Comment: Updated. Thanks for the feedback :)